# How to avoid default errors from a library

Tags: javascript, import, browserify

I have created a code that it actually works, but I call a library that has an error, and I would like to know if it is possible to avoid that specific line of code. I will try to explain the case as well as possible:

**Error**

> Uncaught TypeError: fs.openSync is not a function

**Previous code**

```
function synthesizeToAudioFile(authorizationToken, message) {

    // replace with your own subscription key,
    // service region (e.g., "westus"), and
    // the name of the file you save the synthesized audio.
    var serviceRegion = "westus"; // e.g., "westus"
    var filename = "./audiocue.wav";

    //Use token.Otherwise use the provided subscription key
    var audioConfig, speechConfig;
    audioConfig = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromAudioFileOutput(filename);
    speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromAuthorizationToken(authorizationToken, serviceRegion);

    // create the speech synthesizer.
    var synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

    // start the synthesizer and wait for a result.
    synthesizer.speakTextAsync(message,
        function (result) {
            if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted) {
                console.log("synthesis finished.");
            } else {
                console.error("Speech synthesis canceled, " + result.errorDetails +
                    "\nDid you update the subscription info?");
            }
            synthesizer.close();
            synthesizer = undefined;
        },
        function (err) {
            console.trace("err - " + err);
            synthesizer.close();
            synthesizer = undefined;
        });
    console.log("Now synthesizing to: " + filename);

}
```

I created a method, which later I have replicated in my current code. The difference was that I was using `Browserify` in order to import a library from a `script` of a `HTML` file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dist/sub_mqtt.js"></script>
```

This file had my method, and the whole library, which made it crazy unreadable, and therefore I started using `ScriptJS` to import it. The problem is that, using `browserify` I was able to remove the line of code that it was failing using `fs.openSync`(and I do not even need), but by importing it with `ScriptJS` I do not have access to the source code.

I assume that what is missing is that I am not importing the library `fs`, which is being used by the library that I am importing with `ScriptJS` before importing that one, but how could I do it? I have tried:

```
    <script src="../text-to-speech/node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js"></script>
```

, or

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../text-to-speech/node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js"></script>
```

and also wrapping the content of `synthesizeToAudioFile()` with

```
    require(["node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js"], function (fs) { });
```

but I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
>       at index.js:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching about this question I found out the next statement:

> The fs package on npm was empty and didn't do anything, however many
>   packages mistakenly depended on it. npm, Inc. has taken ownership of
>   it.
>
> It's also a built-in Node module. If you've depended on fs, you can
>   safely remove it from your package dependencies.

therefore what I have done is to access to the file that I was requiring with `ScriptJS`

```
 require(["../text-to-speech/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js"]
```

and directly remove that line on it. Note that, at least in my case, clearing the cache of the browser was needed.